# Triggering <A> Element Without ID or Text

Tags: vba, excel

While setting up an automation process for extracting data from a page, I came across a link where I am having trouble selecting it.
Here is the HTML code:

`<a class="dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblReport" href="#" title="Copy to Clipboard"><span><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg blue"></i></span></a>`

My last attempt was using:

```
For Each m In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If m.className = "dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5" Then
        m.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

With `Dim m As HTMLElementCollection`.

But nothing happens.

If triggered, a window will appear stating that the content has been copied to the clipboard.

Another approach was:

`objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5")(0).Click`

But I get the error message

> Object variable or With block variable not set

objIE is set as:

```
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your page is completely loaded PRIOR to setting your object.

If you are already doing this, sometimes webpages will say they're loaded when they are actually not. To circumvent this, you can loop your object waiting for it to become ready by doing this:

```
Do While objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5")(0) Is Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Then when it's no longer `Nothing`, you can now click it:

```
objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5")(0).Click
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I simply wasn't able to figure out what I was doing wrong. Have a good one!